# Excel Custom Format: How to set a format that handles numbers with optional decimals

Tags: excel

I'm having some trouble with Excel formats:

Example:

Value: 13
Expected result: 13 (not **13.** )
Value: 13.5
Expected result: 13.5 
Value: 13.1234
Expected result: 13.1234

Right now I'm using **#.#** format, but for the first value it always formats with the **.** character at the end. Any ideas?

Edit:
We need to have this working for different number formats (%, $, etc). So we have the some additional examples:

Value: 13
Expected result: $13 (not **$13.** )
Value: $13.5
Expected result: $13.5 
Value: $13.1234
Expected result: $13.1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional formatting.  Use the formula `=a1=round(a1,0)` and set the formatting to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The General format option does that already without any formulas needed.

Comment: You are right, but we need the conditional formatting in case we are using $ columns for example (will update the question to be more specific)